# How to create custom class mimicking Number in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

Here is a case where I would use this.

Imagine an `ArrayIndex` class for traversing arrays. I wanted to be able to get the value of my `ArrayIndex` just like how I receive `number` by just calling the variable. I also wanted to be able to do `+=` operation to my `ArrayIndex`.

Use Case:
You have arrays of text, and you need to turn the following array

```
const input = ["Name", "John Doe", "Social Media", "Name", "Sites", "UID", "Facebook", "www.facebook.com", "1", "Name", "Sites", "UID", "StackOverflow", "www.stackoverflow.com", "2"]
```

To the following output

```
{
  name: "John Doe",
  socialMedia: [{
    name: "facebook",
    link: "www.facebook.com"
  },
  {...}
]
```

Now this is a simple case where there is a data pattern that we can get, like I wanted only to take the social media only. There are data like UID which I don't need.

With my current implementation I have the following class,

```
class ArrayIndex {
  private value: number;

  constructor(initialValue: number = 0) {
    this.value = initialValue;
  }

  // Getter to access the underlying number value
  get index(): number {
    return this.value;
  }

  // Overriding toString() to return the number as a string
  toString(): string {
    return this.value.toString();
  }

  // Overriding valueOf() to return the number when using operators
  valueOf(): number {
    return this.value;
  }
}
```

But the problem is when I tried to use it as an index,

```
const input = ["Name", "John Doe", "Social Media", "Name", "Sites", "UID", "Facebook", "www.facebook.com", "1", "Name", "Sites", "UID", "StackOverflow", "www.stackoverflow.com", "2"]
let index = new TextIndex(5);
console.log(input[index]); // Error: Type 'ArrayIndex' cannot be used as an index type.(2538)
```

With my current `ArrayIndex` class, I cannot use it for indexing array, nor interact it with operators.

I could of course bypass it using just `index.index`, but I was just wondering whether there's the same way we can create the same interaction just like how we use `number` type.

Comment: You can't currently do that with the `Number` class, though. Indexing with a Number object leads to an error [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwTAvDA2gIjpgNDTAIzwOEwF0BuAKGsQXQCYqZW332B6TgeQGk6SdGACmAdxgA5AK4BbQiIQAKRgEoWMbgFEkIBEA) while  `x = new Number(41); x += 1` not only fails to compile but running it will overwrite `x` with a primitive number. [Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/DYUwLgBAHhC8EDsQHcIDkCuBbARiATgBQAsAjAJQDcEAUDANTymU00DGA9ggM4egB0wDgHNCYAJ4AHEBwBm0ADTQIASx5gAhgjYz5mXASpA)

Comment: You should explain why you want to do that. i.e. what would be the use-case?

Comment: @TmTron Newtype pattern, presumably.

Comment: @VLAZ why not use wrapper object like Number()/new Number() to create an instance and use it with instanceof

Comment: @AfzalK. because that's not what the question asks for? It asks for `+=` to work with objects and apparently produce objects. There is no way to overload operators. Yes, sure - you can take a wrapper, apply a number operator to it, then wrap the result back in the wrapper but I struggle to see what is the use of `x = new Number(41); x += 1; x = new Number(x);`

Comment: Thanks @VLAZ for answering! As I wrote this question I just realised that can't be done. But I was wondering whether some of the features I asked can be done. I have added a case where the `ArrayIndex` cannot be used like `Number` in terms of using it as an array index. Do you have any idea about that?